# Hashed Password from Registration Does Not Work in Login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, php-password-hash

So I have created typical registration/login screens for my project.

The registration part appears to be flawless, works like a charm. The password that the user inserts gets hashed into the database, so, for example if the password inserted in registration is the following:

'abcd1234' (without the single quotes)

In the MySQL database it would be stored as the following:

'$2y$10$6MvYy.59NyWsLUHYawc5d.oStB8U9RW8QfwRmMV5urbZUMEWOH7yi' (without the single quotes)

Now the problem is on the login side. When the user tries to login using 'abcd1234', he is unable to login. If he inserts '$2y$10$6MvYy.59NyWsLUHYawc5d.oStB8U9RW8QfwRmMV5urbZUMEWOH7yi' it will work, but I need the user to be able to insert the password 'abcd1234' for login and not the hashed password. I am boggled as to where I went wrong in the code.

Here is my code in the login file (I have this set up to work with a "Remember Me" checkbox):

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require 'dbcon.php';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        
        $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
        $password = addslashes($_POST['password']);
        $remember = $_POST['remember'] ?? null;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' && password = '$password' limit 1";
        $row = query($query);

        if($row) {
            $row = $row[0];
            $_SESSION['SES'] = $row;

            if($remember) {
                $expires = time() + ((60*60*24)*7);
                $salt = "*&salt#@";
                password_hash((time() . $salt),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $tokenkey = hash('sha256', (time() . $salt));
                $tokenvalue = hash('sha256', ('Logged_in' . $salt));

                setcookie('SES', $tokenkey.':'.$tokenvalue, $expires);
                
                $id = $row['id'];
                $query = "UPDATE users SET tokenkey = '$tokenkey', tokenvalue = '$tokenvalue' ";
                $query .= " WHERE id = '$id' limit 1";
                query($query);
            }

            header("Location: index.php");
            die;
        } else {
            echo '<script>
                    window.location.href="login.php";
                    alert("Email or password incorrect");
                    </script>';
        }

    }

?>
```

And here is my code in the registration file:

```
<?php 
    
    session_start();
    require 'dbcon.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $usertype = $_POST['usertype'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $count_username = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $count_email = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count_username == 0 & $count_email == 0) {
            if($password == $cpassword) {
                $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, username, email, usertype, country, password) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$usertype', '$country', '$hash')";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                if($result) {
                    echo '<script>
                    window.location.href="login.php";
                    alert("User registered successfully");
                    </script>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            if($count_username>0) {
                echo '<script>
                    window.location.href="register.php";
                    alert("Username already exists");
                    </script>';
            }
            if($count_email>0) {
                echo '<script>
                    window.location.href="register.php";
                    alert("Email already exists");
                    </script>';
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried to change this line:
$password = addslashes($_POST['password']);

to this:
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

and the query to this:
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' && password = '$hash' limit 1";

But it did not work.

Comment: Your SQL directly compares the raw password with the hash. Clearly that can't ever work. You need to remove the password check from the WHERE clause, get the user's details out of the database, and then run password_verify to compare the hashed and raw passwords. See the duplicate for more details

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data. `addslashes` will do nothing except potentially corrupt the input!

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: **Warning**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong (see above!). It is not generally a good topic for an inexperienced or novice programmer. Any [modern development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. I recommend focusing your time on learning PHP and adding genuine value to your application with new features, not something you can re-use a (reliable, well-made) product for

Comment: Thank you @ADyson ! I have tried to solution in the duplicate, but it did not work - I edited my initial post (towards the end I state what I tried). I may not be applying it properly.

Comment: I admit I am a novice programmer. I am learning coding via Udemy as well as following tutorials for practice as I build my projects. What I find extremely frustrating is the many different ways people code the same thing. As I progress my learning I will eventually understand what is the better or more safer way to code.

Comment: Please DO read the PHP Manual pages for [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) If you had, then I would hope you would also have seen **Warning - The salt option is deprecated. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default. As of PHP 8.0.0, an explicitly given salt is ignored.**

Comment: _I tried to change...._ You will have to remove the password from the WHERE clause of the query as obviously as @ADyson said above **abcd1234** WILL NEVER EQUAL **$2y$10$6MvYy.59NyWsLUHYawc5d.oStB8U9RW8QfwRmMV5urbZUMEWOH7yi** and so the query will not FAIL but will not return an results either

Comment: No, you seem to have misunderstood the guidance. ` password_hash` won't produce the same hash twice for the same input (otherwise it would be far more trivial to crack the hash). As I said, you need to use **password_verify()** to check the password, and remove the password check from the SQL part. You haven't done either of those things. Look at the duplicate guidance again, look at this: https://3v4l.org/7oBG3, and ensure your SQL query _only_ validates the username.

Comment: `What I find extremely frustrating is the many different ways people code the same thing`....sadly, there are a lot of really terrible tutorials and courses out there written by people who barely know what they're doing themselves, just trying to make a few pennies in advertising clicks

Comment: "But it did not work." - what does that mean?